# "Failed Units" while deploying Kubernetes on Azure

Tags: kubernetes

This issue is related to this provisioning workflow: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/azure

The provisioning works fine but as soon as I login into kube-00 (i.e. "ssh -F ./output/kube_7d10e66148c601_ssh_conf kube-00") I constantly see this message:

```
CoreOS stable (647.2.0)
Update Strategy: No Reboots
Failed Units: 2
docker.service
weave-create-bridge.service
```

If I login in into kube-01 and kube-02 there are more services that had failures:

```
CoreOS stable (647.2.0)
Update Strategy: No Reboots
Failed Units: 4
docker.service
kubectl-create-minion.service
weave-create-bridge.service
docker.socket
```

If I login into the etcd nodes they don't show any error (Failed Units).

I have re-deployed the solution at least 10 times. The infrastructure provisioning always goes smooth but the issue above surfaces constantly inside the instances.

Comment: From this output I can see that you are using old version of the code, please checkout master branch. Please note that master branch will give you Kubernetes 1.0 and Weave 1.2 (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/12907).

Comment: thanks @errordeveloper, that made it. I have indeed downloaded a previous releases of the project. Using the master branch solved this particular problem. Onto more testing now. Thanks! PS If you answer this thread as an ANSWER I can vote up it as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This thread was answered in a comment by @errordeveloper:

Use the up-to-date code from the master branch.